Persist usage of Light Theme in the Dev Tools of Chrome Incognito windows
Chrome v128 Dev Tools in an Incognito window.
I can select Settings > Preferences > Appearance > Theme > Light in the Dev Tools section of an incognito window to change the theme temporarily, but this only works as long as the same session runs.
How to persist this setting so that it survives Chrome restarts?

It appears that there is no way to actually accomplish this anymore. There was a Chrome Theme called Material Incognito Light Theme, but it no longer works due to changes by Google. There used to be a Chrome flag that could allow this change to the light theme to occur called incognito-brand-consistency-for-desktop. However, with an update to Chrome back in 2022, even this flag was removed.
Consequently, there appears to be no way to accomplish changing to the light theme for Incognito mode. Sorry, Jürgen. I wish I could give you a better answer.

It seems that DevTools in incognito mode use settings from a regular mode DevTools as a default. You can open DevTools in a regular window, select light theme here and close it to "save" preferences. After that DevTools in new incognito sessions should have light theme.
